# Zoom Down in EXCEL from an ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, excel

Can anybody tell me how to set the zoom factor on an Excel sheet via a ASP.NET application. I believe the Excel Sheet object has a **PageSetup.Zoom** property which does not seem to be working. When I generate a report in Excel programatically through ASP.NET I get the zoom factor of all sheets in the workbook as 100%.

Here is a code sample

```
oSheet.PageSetup.CenterHorizontally = true;
oSheet.PageSetup.CenterVertically = true;
oSheet.PageSetup.Orientation = XlPageOrientation.xlPortrait;
oSheet.PageSetup.PaperSize = XlPaperSize.xlPaperA4;
oSheet.PageSetup.Order = XlOrder.xlDownThenOver;
oSheet.PageSetup.Zoom = 85;
```

Another option is ActiveWindow.Zoom as generated by a macro but it is macro-specific. The whole point of asking this question is after the report has been generated the zoom factor of all the pages in the Excel workbook should be **85%.**
Any inputs would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

[SpreadsheetGear for .NET](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) allows you to set the zoom factor of an Excel worksheet like this:

```
SpreadsheetGear.IWorkbook workbook = SpreadsheetGear.Factory.GetWorkbook();
SpreadsheetGear.IWorksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];
worksheet.WindowInfo.Zoom = 150;
```

Microsoft does not support and recommends against using Office with COM Interop in ASP.NET (see this [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757) KB article).

You can see live C# and VB examples which demonstrate using SpreadsheetGear from ASP.NET [here](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/samples/) and download a free trial [here](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/downloads/register.aspx).

Disclaimer: I own SpreadsheetGear LLC

Answer (score 1):

PageSetup only affects printing. You need to use the Window Zoom. In C# it's something like:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
xlApp.ActiveWindow.Zoom = 150;
```

This only affects the sheet in the active window, not every sheet. You can also set the zoom through the workbook (`wbk.Windows[0].Zoom`) rather than `xlApp.ActiveWindow`.

The way to implement this for all sheets in a `Workbook` object *MyWorkbook* is to select all of the sheets and then hit the *ActiveWindow*:

```
MyWorkbook.Sheets.Select(Type.Missing);
MyWorkbook.Windows[1].Zoom = 150;
```

I tested this and Windows[1] seems to give you document-level customization. I had a problem embedding this code in the workbook's Startup event, but it seems to be fine further down the line.